# Eclipse JSP Formatter using tabs instead of spaces in JSP Scriptlet tags when <script> tags are present

Tags: eclipse, jsp, formatting, bug-reporting

I want to format my JSP page. I am using the JSP Editor. My Eclipse IDE version is Oxygen.1 Release (4.7.1)

Before Formatting:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
<%
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("This line does not have tabs on it!\n");
test.append("This line will have tabs on it.\n");
test.append("This line will too!\n");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function () {
    alert('');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%=test%>
</body>
</html>
```

After Formatting:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
<%
    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("This line does not have tabs on it!\n");
            test.append("This line will have tabs on it.\n");
            test.append("This line will too!\n");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function () {
    alert('');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <%=test%>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what is confusing, if the <script type="text/javascript"> is not in the JSP, there are only spaces in JSP Scriptlet which is the wanted formatting result.

Before Formatting:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
<%
StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("This line does not have tabs on it!\n");
test.append("This line will NOT have tabs on it.\n");
test.append("This line will NOT have tabs on it too!\n");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
function () {
    alert('');
}
</script> -->
</head>
<body>
<%=test%>
</body>
</html>
```

After Formatting:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"%>
<%
    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder("This line does not have tabs on it!\n");
    test.append("This line will NOT have tabs on it.\n");
    test.append("This line will NOT have tabs on it too!\n");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
function () {
    alert('');
}
</script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <%=test%>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Before you ask, In my eclipse preferences I have the following settings:
General > Editors > Text Editors:
Displayed tab width: 4
Insert spaces for tabs is selected

Java > Code Style > Formatter : Click Edit > Indentation > General settings:
Tab policy: Spaces Only
Indentation size: 4
Tab size: 4

JavaScript > Code Style > Formatter : Click Edit > Indentation > General settings:
Tab policy: Spaces Only
Indentation size: 4
Tab size: 4

Web > CSS Files > Editor:
Indent using spaces is selected
Indentation size: 4

Web > HTML Files > Editor:
Indent using spaces is selected
Indentation size: 4

Web > JSP Files > Editor:
Format JSP XML documents as HTML is selected

XML > XML Files > Editor:
Indent using spaces is selected
Indentation size: 4

If you have any other eclipse preferences questions, please ask.

Comment: Don't use scriptlets. They are bad.

Comment: @AleksandrM I know scriptlets are bad, but I am in a situation where removing scriptlets is out of my control.

Comment: Interesting. I confirm, this is happening in my setup as well. You can try to post this into Eclipse bug tracker.

Comment: @AleksandrM I will try the Eclipse bug tracker and I will post back here if I get any more info on this.